# Sherlock ActionBar nowadays

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to implement Sherlock ActionBar, but I'm not getting... Seems It's too old.

Does it have an equivalent ActionBar, or someone have a new tutorial ?

Comment: Use `appcompat-v7` library and try using the `Toolbar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActionBarSherlock was deprecated two years ago. Either use the native action bar that is part Android (from API Level 11 onwards), or use Google's `appcompat-v7` action bar backport in the Android Support library. Both are covered in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html).